# Access to C:\grldr is denied

Tags: installation, multi-boot, android

I have an old PC on which I wanted to play PUBG, Hopeless land and others.
No emulator was compatible to run on such a low end PC. So I decided to install an android OS to my hard drive D:. I chose prime OS for this. I know that exe installer is available but i already have 4 partitions meaning that the Installer cannot create another partition for itself. So to install prime OS on my hard disk, I ended up at installing the ISO of prime OS to D: with Androidx86 installer. Drive D: has a 40gb space and I have no problem if I am asked to leave the full drive for prime OS. Here is what I did after formatting D::

1. Installed Androidx86 installer v12.
2. Downloaded prime OS latest 32-bit ISO from official website.
3. In the Android installer I selected the ISO, and target drive D: with max user size of 32gb.
4. Then clicked on "Install now".

As soon as I hit install now. I got the error as the title says.
I checked my C:\ drive, it did not have any grldr file 
I looked into the D: and saw a folder named **Android** upon opening which I did not see much stuff (not like how it should have been) but I found a grldr.mbr in it after exploring those KB's.
I simply Copy & Pasted it to C:\ yet I got the same error. Here are my old PC's specifications:

- 1GB RAM.
- Intel G33/G31 express chipset family graphics (Integrated).
- Intel Pentium dual CPU E2200 @ 2.20ghz processor.
- 32-bit windows 7 ultimate and 64-bit capable CPU.
- BIOS.
- PCI-E.

Please give me a fix.

I only want to install an android OS that can help me play those games on my PC so if any of you have a good alternative that can install without errors then tell me in comments but I want to install only on hard drive so tell me a way to do that in case any of you give an ISO. Ask any information that you want respected users and developers.

Comment: Give up now. Even to play it on a phone you need 2GB RAM. That machine is just 10 years too old & 10 times too slow. It was a low-end machine even when it was new. Sorry.

Comment: @Tetsujin I found the solution.